# Javascript Clickable instead of Automatically Pop Up

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Heading ##Good day! I have issues with this javascript codes. This code is intended for Pop Only. I'm thinking, how can I convert this to an clickable image.

here is the code of my image

```
<li><a href="#"><i class="icon-envelope icon-2x"></i></a></li>
```

And here is my pop up javascript codes from "Klaviyo"

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.klaviyo.com/media/js/public/klaviyo_subscribe.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    (document).ready(function(){
    $('icon-envelope icon-2x').on('click',function(){
 KlaviyoSubscribe.attachModalSignUp({
        list: 'g9cZtX',
        delay_seconds: 0.5,
        content: {
            clazz: ' klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX',
            header: "Interested in our Newsletter?",
            subheader: "Stay in the know with news and promotions.",
            button: "Subscribe",
            success: "Thanks! Check your email for a confirmation.",
            styles: '.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX {  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial}.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_header {  color:#222;}.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_subheader {  color:#222;}.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_submit_button,.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_submit_button span {  background-color:#07234F;  background-image: none;   border-radius: 2px;}.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_submit_button:hover,.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_submit_button span:hover {  background-color:#2A4D85;  background-image: none; }.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_inner,.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_fieldset .klaviyo_field_group input[type=text],.klaviyo_modal.klaviyo_modal_g9cZtX .klaviyo_fieldset .klaviyo_field_group input[type=email] {  border-radius: 2px;}'
        }
    });
});
});
    </script>
```

I'm not sure where is my error. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Fix

`(document).ready(function(){`   to   `$(document).ready(function(){`

and

`$('icon-envelope icon-2x').on('click',function(){` to `$('.icon-envelope').on('click',function(){`

Comment: Sir I already fixed that. Still sir, nothing happens. There is no pop up when I click the image. What do I gonna do sir?

Comment: now something wrong with code at KlaviyoSubscribe.attachModalSignUp or parameters passed, it should be now calling KlaviyoSubscribe.attachModalSignUp method that you can test by adding an alert('test') in that method.